# Why is the backup of the site not behaving the same as the original?

Tags: 7

I've cloned my site onto a testing server prior to making changes (database and all files), but it's not behaving like the original, and I'm unable to login.

The site was at www.original.com/drupal/ and www.original.com/node/3 works.
The test site is at www.test.com (note no /drupal) and www.test.com/node/3 gives me an Apache 404 error page.

Why are the two sites not behaving the same?
No Drupal specific content resides above www.original.com/drupal.

Comment: Did you also copy the .htaccess file? Or maybe there is some configuration in the apache virtual host... compare these on the two systems.

Comment: By default, if you install Drupal in a sub-directory (e.g. drupal), the URL for the node with ID equal to 3 would be http://example.com/drupal/node/3; if you see the content at http://example.com/node/3, then some of the files (e.g. .htaccess) have been changed.

Comment: @kiamlauno: I moved the contents of `/drupal` to `/`, hence `drupal` is missing from the URLs

Comment: @Bedir: there was a .htaccess at `/` but it did not contain any drupal specifics.

Comment: And does the .htaccess exist on the test site too? Does www.test.com/?q=node/3 work? If yes, then you are either missing the .htaccess on your test installation or it is incorrect.

Comment: Hah, you're pretty good with incorrectly writing usernames by the way. If you write it correctly, those persons are automatically notified and might otherwise not look at the question again, so make sure you write the name correctly :)

Comment: Multitasking - it's a false economy

Comment: there exists `original.com/.htaccess` and `original.com/drupal/.htaccess` but only the latter remains and it is at `test.com/.htcccess`.
`?q=node/3` works as expected on both original and test sites

Comment: The problem was caused by the .htaccess not being processed due to AllowOverride None in my httpd.conf file. Changing to AllowOverride All and restarting apache cured it.
Thanks @Berdir!

Comment: Great. Please write that down as an answer and accept it (once you can) so that this question is properly marked as fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was caused by .htaccess not being processed due to the "AllowOverride None" directive in my "httpd.conf" file.

Changing to "AllowOverride All" and restarting Apache cured it.